# How can I quote a variable?

Tags: c, variables, quotes

How can I quote a variable in C?

I have this:

```
inputpass[0] = selectorValue;
```

And doesnt return the expected result.

Works fine with:

```
inputpass[0] = '1';
```

I need to put the variable **selectorValue** between single quotes. ¿How can I do that?

I tried with `inputpass[0] = "'" + selectorValue + "'"` but didn't work.

I want to make a char array, and selectorValue is an integer variable. That's why I want to put it between single quotes.

Comment: You're misunderstanding data types.  It sounds like you're actually asking how to convert a number to a string.

Comment: What is selectorValue? It looks like it's a `char`. Further, what is `inputpass`? It looks like an array to a `char`. If both of those are right, then what do you mean by "doesn't return the expected result"? Either way, your last attempt doesn't look correct.

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing what `inputpass` and `selectorValue` are. You say it "doesn't return the expected result"; what did you expect, and what did you get? Read this: http://sscce.org

Comment: To me, it's unclear what you mean with "quote a variable". Do you need `inputpass[0] = '0' + selectorValue`, maybe?

Comment: There is no need. Probably `inputpass[0] = selectorValue + '0';` is OK.

Comment: Please, improve the details of your question: explain what are the types of you are declared for your variables.

Comment: Where does this come from: "selectorValue is an interger variable. **That's why** I want to put it between single quotes" ? I don't follow this line of thinking.

Comment: @Jongware: The OP is not understanding what a char constant is in C.

Comment: @Jongware: In his comment, the OP tolds me this: "Sólo quiero que inputpass[0] tenga como valor la variable selectorValue pero encerrada entre comillas simples." Translation: I only want that inputpass[0] has the value of the variable selectorValue, but enclosed in single quotes. He is working with options having numbers like 1, 2, 3, ..., and he wants '1', '2', '3', ..., maybe to convert to "char" and show the result in its Arduino project. Whatever...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you want to quot a variable, but I think you possibly are missunderstanding the way in that characters work in C.
In C, a character constant, like `'1'`, has a value of type `int`, that is, an integer.
If your variable `selectorValue` is an integer, then nothing is needed to do.

I imagine that `selectorValue` is an integer like 1, 2, 3, ...

In this case, if you want to convert it to a character, you have to add the ASCII value of '0' to the integer, in this way:

```
    inputpass[0] = '0' + selectorValue;
```

But this approach only works with values between 0 and 9. So, be carefull.

Anyway, I am guessing, because your question is not very clear.

Finally, in C, what makes the difference between the ASCII code of a character, for example 'A' (which is 64) and the character itself, comes in the moment that you have to show the information.

```
   printf("%c", 'A');  // Prints the character: A
   printf("%d", 'A');  // Prints the ASCII value of the character A: 64
```

**The OP explains that he want to "add" single quotes, explicitely.**

I think to achieve this could be very complicated, if not impossible.
In this moment I cannot see or remember the way to do that.
(To add double quotes is easy, by using the operator `#` in macro definition).

Comment: Sólo quiero que inputpass[0] tenga como valor la variable selectorValue pero encerrada entre comillas simples.

Comment: English is mandatory in this website. [Se exige inglés en esta web] Anyway, why do you want to put single quotes? [De cualquier manera, para qué quieres poner comillas simples?] What you want can be done with a macro, but it is not the right approach. [Lo que quieres hacer es posible con una macro, pero no es la mejor manera de lograrlo.] To add the value of '0' is better. [Sumar el valor entero de '0' es mejor]. I will show you the macro approach, anyway. [Te voy a mostrar el método con macros de todos modos.]

Comment: Thanks!!! I'm working with arduino and selectorValue is an analog input from a potentiometer (a source of wheel that when you spin it, you change the analog voltage that returns). I stored that information in an interger variable. Then, I wanted to make an array for typing a password, so every character of the password is selectorValue's value.

Comment: @user3760711: Actually, I cannot remember an easy (even a possible) way to add single quotes with a macro. Double quotes can be added with the # operator.